# How does the Hutchinson Effect work?

Tags: electromagnetism, metals

I have seen pictures online of metal ripped apart and metal completely messed up due to the [Hutchinson Effect](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=hutchison+effect). How does this effect work and what are the other principles behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't real. [source 1](http://skepdic.com/hutchisonhoax.html) [source 2](http://mysteriousuniverse.org/2014/02/the-hutchison-effect-the-mahabharata-and-acoustic-levitation/)

"One suggestion made by skeptics is that Hutchison uses an electromagnet on the ceiling, and places hidden pieces of metal inside objects so they will be attracted to the magnet. He could then film the objects with an upside-down camera as he powers down the electromagnet, making the objects on film appear to float up and out of the shot when in reality they are falling down to the floor. Many of the videos include conspicuous objects in the scene which do not move (such as an old broom), which could be deliberately attached to add to the illusion that the camera is not upside-down. Critics also point out that the videos do not show what happens to the objects after they levitate."

It is supposed to use zero-point energy, which is real, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. It's too bad that there are people lying about discoveries.

Comment: A useful replication of the Hutchison Anti-Gravity Effect for anyone who stumbles on this question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8uUZtJjz8Q